# Component inheritance from templates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

**Motivation**

There are uncountable amount of scenarios where we would want multiple components to have the same features. Obviously, we don't want to (and shouldn't!!) just copy child components over. This is what object-oriented programming concept called inheritance is good for.

For example, in my case, we want to have this `<loader>` on all the pages/derived components that could load. We'd do something like create a `BaseComponent` that has this `<loader>` in its template, with methods to show and hide it (e.g. `showLoader()`,`hideLoader()`) .

**How to implement in other framework/library**

Coming from a React + MobX background, I'd be careful to do something like the following:

`BaseView.js` :

```
@observer
export class BaseView extends Component { 

    

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        
        // NOTE: this could be stored in the view model MobX store being passed in as prop, too...
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
        }
    }
    
    showLoader() {
        // NOTE: we could just change it on the view model, too...
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            isLoading: true,
        })
    }
    
    hideLoader() {
        // NOTE: we could just change it on the view model, too...
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            isLoading: false,
        })
    }
    
    renderContent() { 
        // to be implemented by derived component
    }
    
    render() { 
        return <Fragment>
        {
            // note: we could also mount/unmount the component, preventing having to React to a prop/state change as well
            (this.state.isLoading) && 
                React.createPortal(<Loader />, 
                    document.querySelector('#loader-container')
                )
                
        }
        {
            this.renderContent()
        }
        </Fragment>
    }
}
```

`DerivedView.js` would just be :

```
@observer
export default DerivedView extends BaseView { 
    renderContent() { 
        return <Fragment>
            <code style={{whiteSpace: pre}}>
                Your content go in here and replace this code tag
            </code>
        </Fragment>
    }
}
```

**The problem**

Coming back to Angular, after two years, I can't think of how to go about doing something like this in it.

I know there is `template` and `templateUrl` tags, for when you want to define the template in the same file as the controller, or refer to an HTML file to separate concerns, respectively. I know that both of these get defined in the class decorator function `@Component`.

`templateUrl` refer to HTML file, which has no concept of inheritance. I don't want to mix view and controller/viewmodel concerns either, because that would be bullshit design.

`template` allow us to define the content as ES6 string, which would lean towards what I want, but we risk mixing the view and controller/viewmodel concern.

How to accomplish the inheritance design pattern in Angular without mixing concerns, and without basically hacking?

Comment: Does react documentation recommend inheritance or composition? https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html . That being said, maybe consider composition over inheritance with angular also. Also you’re using setState in your react components instead setting state directly right?

Comment: It doesn't recommend it, but at my day job, we came up with a system around that non-recommendation. 

As for the `setState()`, ya, we should use that instead. In my defense, I was just "whiteboarding" up an example real quick lol

Comment: The composition is a quick loosely coupled way to go about it, but it can become a nightmare to maintain. 

Literally, you'd have to memorize the prop structure of the "base" and "derived" components. 

I use the idea of it at work: when we extend a component with some business logic in it, I still have to, being careful, call the base component, spreading props to it, in the render function. That or the idiomatic thing: to just fill in the methods defined in the base.

Comment: I think in most situations the paradigm in angular it’s going to be a lot different without the equivalent of a render function or render props. It does however allow for transclusion/children which can work well with composition pattern. That being said, classes can implement/extend multiple interfaces/classes so you have the opportunity to enforce implementation of methods. You cannot extend a component in angular to extend its template, that’s why composition can help to share common logic.

Answer (score -1):

It's not necesarrily that you would want to focus on the `template` or the `templateUrl`.

All you need to do is create the component with a `selector` and use that in your other components templates (the HTML files).

Psuedo code setup for your loader component

```
// loader.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.html'
})
export class LoaderComponent {
// class level things here like inputs, lifecycle hooks, dependency injection, etc.
// this is where you could determine what to hide and show in the template.
}
```

```html
<!-- loader.component.html -->
loader works!
```

And then in your Base Components .html

```html
<!-- base.component.html -->
base works!
<loader></loader>
```

Comment: Would I necessarily be stuck with copy and paste that `<loader>` to the derived components?

Say, for example, page-level components and modal/form components.

Please complete this answer.

Comment: You would need to have ```<loader></loader>``` in the other components, yes. 

You cant extend the template, but you could extend some functions in the loader if you needed, in another component. However, if you kept your logic for hiding and showing to the loader template, you would only have to worry about that logic once (which would then be in the loader component). 

Are you looking to change the hide and show logic multiple times?

Comment: That doesn't work. 

The point is modularity, which clearly this default approach does not have.